# Render slow, console log "Using fallback" and after start render process

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, command-line

When I want render an image to animation, I prefer to render by CLI. It's more quiet. But my last render appear with this message

```
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
Using fallback
```

Why?

Comment: I have the same happening. No clue so far!